# HandsonTable - div class "WtHolder" Automatic Height Calculation Incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, handsontable

I am trying to have HandsonTable automatically adjust its width and height to the size of the div container it is associated to, in this case lets call it "test". I have followed the HandsonTable guide (see link below) on achieving this and it says to leave the height and width settings unspecified and "the table will vertically and horizontally fill the entire window".

https://handsontable.com/blog/articles/a-complete-guide-to-changing-size-of-handsontable

My code to achieve this is provided below:

```
var container = document.getElementById('test');

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
        data: data()
      });
```

However when the size of my container changes and my handsontable is re-rendered, the height property is not set to the new height of the modified container. Instead it is set to some strange height calculation.

By looking at the source code elements it is possible to identify the culprit which is the "WtHolder" div element which uses some strange calculation to set the height of itself. See code below.

```
<div class="wtHolder" style="position: relative;width: 494.5px;height: calc(50% - 4px);">
```

So is there a way to always ensure this height value is set to 100% of the div containers height?

Thanks in advance for any help!